# ¿Como guardo una huella digital DigitalPersona UareU 4500 en sql?

Tags: java, sql, huelladigital

estoy realizando la programacion en java de un lector de huellas DP UareU 4500, estoy trabajando con la SDK 2.3 la cual me ofrece los metodos que necesito pero no satisface del todo mis necesidades, lo que no logro comprender aun es como almacenar la huella tomada en sql para posteriormente hacer un Identify, les muestro el codigo que utilizo para crear el template (Tomado del SDK):

```
EnrollmentThread.EnrollmentEvent evt = (EnrollmentThread.EnrollmentEvent)e;
        
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals(EnrollmentThread.ACT_PROMPT)){
            if(m_bJustStarted){
                m_text.append("El registro ha comenzado\n");
                m_text.append("    coloque algun dedo en el lector\n");
            }
            else{
                m_text.append("    coloque el mismo dedo en el lector\n");
            }
            m_bJustStarted = false;
        }
        else if(e.getActionCommand().equals(EnrollmentThread.ACT_CAPTURE)){
            if(null != evt.capture_result){
                MessageBox.BadQuality(evt.capture_result.quality);
            }
            else if(null != evt.exception){
                MessageBox.DpError("Capture", evt.exception);
            }
            else if(null != evt.reader_status){
                MessageBox.BadStatus(evt.reader_status);
            }
            m_bJustStarted = false;
        }
        else if(e.getActionCommand().equals(EnrollmentThread.ACT_FEATURES)){
            if(null == evt.exception){
                m_text.append("    huella capturada!\n\n");
            }
            else{
                MessageBox.DpError("Feature extraction", evt.exception);
            }
            m_bJustStarted = false;
        }
        else if(e.getActionCommand().equals(EnrollmentThread.ACT_DONE)){
            if(null == evt.exception){
                String str = String.format("    el registro de la huella fue exitoso, size: %d\n\n\n", evt.enrollment_fmd.getData().length);
                m_text.append(str);
            }
            else{
                MessageBox.DpError("Enrollment template creation", evt.exception);
            }
            m_bJustStarted = true;
        }
        else if(e.getActionCommand().equals(EnrollmentThread.ACT_CANCELED)){
            //canceled, destroy dialog
            m_dlgParent.setVisible(false);
        }
        
        //cancel enrollment if any exception or bad reader status
        if(null != evt.exception){
            m_dlgParent.setVisible(false);
        }
        else if(null != evt.reader_status && Reader.ReaderStatus.READY != evt.reader_status.status && Reader.ReaderStatus.NEED_CALIBRATION != evt.reader_status.status){
            m_dlgParent.setVisible(false);
        }
```

Esto me estaria creando mi objeto de tipo Fmd, pero aca es donde no logro resolver como continuar, este objeto tiene el metodo getData() el cual me devuelve un dato de tipo Byte[], creo que es por aca pero me serviria los consejos que puedan darme, muchas gracias.

Comment: Que formatos de huella devuelve tu lector, tienes un formato FMD?

Comment: `String str = String.format(" ", evt.enrollment_fmd.getData().length);`,  Este  string contiene tu huella ?

Comment: @EmersonRios el lector me devuelve un FMD, y se guarda en evt.enrollment_fmd

Comment: Puedes referirte a esta guía completa [Guía Implementacion en Java](https://github.com/ankit4u3/Digital-Persona), la parte de almacenar esta en el archivo Enrollment en la linea 278  :`db.Insert(this.username_text.getText(),this.enrollmentFMD.getData());`, si tienes dudas, edita tu pregunta.